# nested query using ntile aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query;

```
select token, average, ntile(100) over (order by average) as percentile 
from responses;
```

How can I return a specific row from this using the `token` field? Ideally in one query, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select r.*
from (select token, average, ntile(100) over (order by average) as percentile 
      from responses
     ) r
where token = <whatever>;
```

If you just add a `where` clause to your query, it will be applied before the window function and affect the results.